# ASP.NET MVC4 Redirect to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a web application using ASP.NET MVC 4 and C#.

I want all users to be logged in before using application.

I'm using ASP.NET Membership with a custom database.

One method is check if `Membership.GetUser()` is null or not in every function.

**But isn't there any easier way than checking user login state in every function?** (maybe checking in web.config, global.asax, etc...??)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Sure, decorate your actions or the whole class with [`[Authorize]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) and it will require that the user is logged in first.

Comment: And how ASP.NET MVC knows where is my login page?

Comment: The attribute forces a 401 error code to be returned which kicks in ASP.NET's normal authorization module. You can then set the login page in `web.config` (or use the default).

Comment: You would do that in your web.config. Under the `<authentication>` attribute.

Comment: And how to do that in `web.config`?

Comment: There's a section called `<authentication>`. in there, you'll have a line like `<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />` just change the URL there.

Comment: It's in the `<authentication mode="Forms">` tag, under `<forms ... loginurl='login' ...>`.

Answer (score 13):

Put `[Authorize]` over each action that you want only logged in users accessing. You can also do this at the controller level, making all actions within the controller secured. The latter is probably best for you, since you probably only want all of your pages disabled for guests.

Here's what the class-level one looks like:

```
[Authorize]
public class SomethingController
{
    //...
}
```

and here's an action-level one:

```
public class SomethingController
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult SomeAction(Parameter someParameter)
    {
        //...   
    }
}
```

Another way to do it, if all or most of your pages use the same master page, is to put:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    @if(!Request.IsAuthenticated) {
        window.location.href = redirectURL;
    }
</script>
```

or if you arent using razor syntax,

```
<script type="text/javascript>  
    <% if(!Request.IsAuthenticated) { %>
        window.location.href = redirectURL;
    <% } %>
</script>
```

in the master page. That way, all pages which use that master page will redirect elsewhere if the user is not logged in. This only applies if you are using the built-in authentication, though.  ***NOTE: This option is far less secure than the first option. Use this only if site security is not a big concern***

Comment: How is an answer promoting client-side authentication the accepted answer in 2012...

Comment: @Blindy perhaps because I listed it in there as an alternative to the way I would do it? There are several applications where client side auth isn't such a bad thing, you know.

Comment: @Blindy lol, way to indirectly steal rep from an answer that took me 10 minutes to write up. Not to mention the fact that the level of detail between your answer and mine is not even comparable.

Comment: @Blindy stateless servers? Low-volume, low-security websites?

Comment: Huh? What's wrong with my answer? You don't need specific code examples that don't even DO anything to get the point across, "decorate the action or the whole class" is very, very specific. And doesn't advocate client-side "security". If I had the time I'd look up that famous daily wtf article about that government site, you made me think of it right away..

Comment: (And it wasn't that indirect, the -1 is mine).

Comment: @Blindy any answer that you have to add multiple comments to in order to clarify is not a good answer. (And I was referring to the fact that seconds after you commented, the OP changed the accepted answer to yours, when mine was perfectly fine)

Comment: @Blindy also, the OP simply wants to force users to log in before going to other pages. Security isn't the only reason for that. Maybe it just doesn't make sense for users to see certain things if they aren't members. In that case, my client-side solution would suffice just fine.

Comment: My comments were to extra questions, nowhere in the OP did he ask about the specific login page location. This is rather pointless, you haven't even given me reason to revert my -1..

Comment: @Blindy That's ok, keep your -1.

Comment: @Blindy but just so you can't say this answer isn't better, I edited it just for you!

Comment: -1 from me (please don't take it personally). Not a good approach and makes no sense no matter what. Never use a client side solution for security. I remember web sites on GeoCities in 1995 that did this and it was the norm back then. Not recommended.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question already has an answer but if the intention is to lock down the whole app except for a select few controller actions then I feel like this is a better solution ...

In the startup / init for your app add ...

```
httpConfig.filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
```

... then on actions you **DONT** want to secure ...

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Hello() { return View(); }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could write a custom `[Authorize]` attribute. Then simply decorate controllers/actions with it or if all actions require authorization you could register it as a global action filter.

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: Simply derive from AuthorizeAttribute and override the AuthorizeCore method.

Answer (score 4):

You can put `[Authorize]` attribute at your controller or at single methods in your controller so you would choose who can open the actions and with what permissions. You can also authorize with roles like : `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]` where you will authorize only users in admin role to access your action/controller. For example:

```
[Authorize(Roles="SimpleUser")] or with no roles [Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
{
    ... whatever logic
    return View();
}
```

Hope this helps ;]

Answer (score 2):

Use [Authorize] at the class level

if you want to allow anonymous access to some actions use [AllowAnonymous]