What make .net framework web app open to login screen?
I am developing two .Net Framework Web app projects that will have user account authentication. When I run the first one, it automatically adds /account/login to the URL and goes to the login page. The other does not. I can't figure out what setting makes the first project correctly redirect to account/login, but is missing from the second project. Anyone?

Found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672542/asp-net-mvc4-redirect-to-login-page
